# php logout doesnt work

Tags: php, authentication

My problem may seem pretty elementary, but I dont know whats wrong with my code. I have a very simple login system that looks like this:

login.php:

```
<?php  
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1) {
   header("Location: admin.php");
}

if ($_GET['login']) {
     // Only load the code below if the GET
     // variable 'login' is set. You will
     // set this when you submit the form

     if ($_POST['username'] == 'thenemis'
         && $_POST['password'] == 'slustice') {
         // Load code below if both username
         // and password submitted are correct

         $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
          // Set session variable

         header("Location: admin.php");
         exit;
         // Redirect to a protected page

     } else echo "Wrong details";
     // Otherwise, echo the error message
}
?>

<form action="?login=1" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">  
                <fieldset>
                  <label for="username">Usermame:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required>
                  <label for="password">Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
                  <input type="submit" value="Login"> </td>
                </fieldset>
</form>
```

This works fine.

admin.php:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    // Call this function so your page
    // can access session variables

    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
        // If the 'loggedin' session variable
        // is not equal to 1, then you must
        // not let the user see the page.
        // So, we'll redirect them to the
        // login page (login.php).

        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

?>

<p><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></p>
```

Now my problem is, that the system keeps me logged even though i clicked the logout URL, which looks like this:

logout.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

There is obviously some elementary mistake with my logout procedure, but I cant seem to find it... Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making assignment here:

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1) {
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

and you should make comparisment

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) {
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `admin.php` file

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

?>

<p><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In login.php you didn't started session_start after user details verified...

try to add session_start(); before $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;

This may work for you...

in logout.php

before estroying unset the session variable 
using this line

unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);

Answer (score 0):

From the [php.net Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> In order to kill the session altogether, **like to log the user out**, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

Use [this code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#example-4632) (copied from php.net) to logout securely:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Just try with the following changes :***

**In login.php :**

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) {
   header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

**In logout.php :**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION['loggedin']=""; //Just empty that session variable
    header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.